# How to get values from logs in alerts text message in Elasticsearch Kiban

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, alert

I am continuously sending health data of my Ubuntu machine to elasticsearch using td-agent. This health data contains cpu temperature which I have to monitor. So I have created alerts in which is the temperature value increses to more than 60*F, it gives alerts on my Microsoft Teams channel. This all setup is working fine.

Below is the logs data:

```
{
  "_index": "health_skl_gateway",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "DwxjinkBwxSy0OQ_4rhS",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "Data": {
      "WiFiIP": "N/A",
      "signal_strength": "N/A",
      "signal_percent": 0,
      "signal_level": "N/A",
      "EthIP": "192.168.100.30 ",
      "TotalDisk": "916G",
      "UsedDisk": "40G",
      "FreeDisk": "830G",
      "DiskPercent": "5%",
      "TotalRAM": "16312468",
      "UsedRAM": "3735596",
      "FreeRAM": "5866548",
      "CPU": 27,
      "cpu_temp": 57,
      "Internet": true,
      "Publish msg count": 442,
      "Created": "2021-05-20T15:26:51.557564",
      "DeviceId": "TX-G1-318",
      "UpTime": "2021-05-19T07:13:05"
    },
    "hostname": "TX-G1-318",
    "Version": "V2"
  },
  "fields": {
    "Data.UpTime": [
      "2021-05-19T07:13:05.000Z"
    ],
    "Data.Created": [
      "2021-05-20T15:26:51.557Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1621524411557
  ]
}
```

In alerting of Kibana, I have set alerts in which if the `count` is 3, of all documents of index `health_skl_gateway`, for last `10 minutes`, where `Data.cpu_temp` is greater than `60`, it generates alerts to Microsoft Teams channel. Now below is how I have configured the message which is sent to Microsoft teams

[image]

So in the message, I am just sending the static text message. But I want to send the actual `Data.cpu_temp` value in the messsage.

Is this possible. How can we do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using double braces? Like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alerting-getting-started.html). I guess mapping is done in the same way for all alert types.

> In the server monitoring example, the email action type is used, and server is mapped to the body of the email, using the template string CPU on {{server}} is high.

Comment: I didn't get you. How do I use Data.cpu_temp value in message format.?

Comment: My idea was something along the lines of `{{data.cpu_temp}}` or so. Kibana messages are using [mustache template syntax](https://mustache.github.io). It also seems that fields you can use in message are limited, but you should check what is available for your case, it's described [https://mustache.github.io](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/defining-alerts.html#defining-alerts-actions-details).

Comment: I actually tried using `{{Data.cpu_temp}} but it didn't worked.